# What is the difference between getIntent() and getting intent from savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi all I'm trying out the android passing of intents between 2 classes and I've realized there are 2 methods to passing intents ,

The first is using getIntent method here:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mRowId = (extras != null) ? extras.getLong(DrugsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;
```

And the second method is accessing the savedInstanceState:

```
mRowId = (savedInstanceState != null) savedInstanceState.getLong(DrugsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;
```

In both methods I'm trying to access the RowId which I can then use to fetchData. Whats the difference between both methods ? Which one is better ?

Comment: Do you get your rowId in 2nd case? I assume you don't, because `savedInstanceState` is empty unless you put there something in `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: For the record, the second method is not getting or "passing intents." Both methods are getting a *Bundle* of key-value pairs. Presumably that's what you meant. `getIntent().getExtras()` gives you something analogous to the parameters passed to a constructor. `savedInstanceState` is more like the state of the activity that was saved at some point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first case gives you the extras of the intent that started this activity, while the second one is used when `onCreate` is invoked the 2nd and more time, for example, on device rotate. That bundle should be populated in `onSaveInstanceState`.

Comment: Now I'm trying to understand this - if the user rotates the screen, does the Activity receive again the same Intent that it received when it was first created?

Comment: getIntent() will return the same intent with the same extras. But the Bundle argument of onSaveInstanceState is a different thing.

Answer (score 11):

[getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) is used to tell you which `Intent` started this `Activity`.  It is accessible anywhere in the `Activity`.  It has a `Bundle`, but it also has other metadata.

`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` passes you a `Bundle`, to persist instance variables in your app until next start.  This `Bundle` only comes in `onCreate()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, and it has no other data.